# using break in try/except block doesn't exit loop at the point. why is that?

Tags: python, while-loop

why does **finally section** run although I use **break** in else section

```py
while 1:
    try:
        print(2)
    except:
        print("err")
    else:
        print("we are in else part")
        break
    finally:
        print("we are in finally part")
```

both else and finally sections run once

shouldn't **break** exit the while loop at the point?

thanks :)

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: The `finally` clause *always runs*.  That's the whole point of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

> If the `try` statement reaches a `break`, `continue` or `return` statement, the `finally` clause will execute just prior to the `break`, `continue` or `return` statement’s execution.

This allows the `finally` clause to ensure that resources are released no matter how the `try` is exited. For instance, you might put the code to close a file in the `finally` clause, and it should be executed even if you break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if you copy-pasted wrong but you missed an indentation. I tried

```py
while 1:
    try:
        print(2)
    except:
        print("err")
    else:
        print("we are in else part")
        break
    finally:
        print("we are in finally part")
""" (output)
2
we are in else part
we are in finally part
"""
```

and it worked.

Comment: This isn't an answer.